# Visual Studio Code не запускает JS

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-code

Только установил VSC на шиндовс и пошли пляски...
пытаюсь заранить код

```
alert('sad');
```

а в ответ получаю:

```
[Running] node "e:\JS\new.js"
"node" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.019 seconds
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - все ли поймут Вас? Все ли условия Вы описали?

Comment: как вы запускаете? используете ли js фреймеврк? при чем тут vs code (не нравиться - работайте в notpad++ ... правда вот тут начнутся пляски). Это весь код, который есть в файле?Где `html`?

Comment: шиндовс - это сильно )

Comment: В NodeJS не определена функция `alert()`, если что.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь запустить парсер Node.JS который не знает что такое `alert`. Тоже самое будет и с `prompt`. Node.js не знает что это такое, так как эти методы предоставляет браузер, как и другие объекты по типу `navigator`, `window.history` и другие.